# Google Play store reject app due to non-certified ad SDK, React Native

Tags: react-native, google-play, admob, ads, firebase-admob

When publishing the app on Google Play, we encountered the problem "Your app includes non-certified advertising SDKs»

In short, this means that our advertising SDK does not meet the requirements of Google.
Our application falls into the group "for children".

We also participate in the ["Apps for the Whole Family"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9893335) program

For advertising, we use `react-native-firebase/admob`
After checking the list of certified SDKs, we found admob there. That is, everything should be fine with this point.

Next, we configured the request to receive ads, as required by Google.

```js
admob()
  .setRequestConfiguration({
    maxAdContentRating: MaxAdContentRating.G,
    tagForChildDirectedTreatment: true,
    tagForUnderAgeOfConsent: true,
  })
```

After resending the application, we received another failure with the same reason.
There were attempts to send the app with both the expo sdk and the bare react-native.
This also failed to produce any results.

Our package.json looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "My Little Genius",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/admob": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "expo-av": "^9.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.1",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-looped-carousel": "^0.1.13",
    "react-native-orientation-locker": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.8.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-rename": "^2.8.1",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.13.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-native-confetti-cannon": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-drax": "^0.8.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

We have studied the documentation, but have not found a solution to our problem. It is also not entirely clear why Google swears at the advertising SDK, if we use an SDK from the list of certified ones.

Comment: There is a thing called SDK Index (https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=843528c57ee37d67JmltdHM9MTY4OTgxMTIwMCZpZ3VpZD0yNTk1ODkwMC1jMzQzLTZlMWUtMmFmZS05OWJjYzc0MzZjM2YmaW5zaWQ9NTE4Mw&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=25958900-c343-6e1e-2afe-99bcc7436c3f&psq=programmatically+get+list+of+google+play+store+approved+sdk&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXZlbG9wZXIuYW5kcm9pZC5jb20vZGlzdHJpYnV0ZS9zZGstaW5kZXg&ntb=1), but I have also tried to look for API way to retrieve list of all approved/supported/certified SDKs with no luck up to the date.